# How to store the value entered dynamically in a form made in jsp into arraylist?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

On clicking the button add organisation, a form gets displayed with parameters `ID` and `NAME`. After inputting the `ID` and `NAME` when the user clicks the submit button, the given entry should get stored and when the main table of organisation is viewed in home page it should have the values entered by the user. You can make use of anything `MVC` `JSP` `JAVA` or anything.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title> Organization List</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border= '1' class="floatedTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Organization ID</th>
        <th>Organization Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Tieto</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Microsoft</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Google</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Chevron</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>
<table border= '1'  class="floatedTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Employee Address</th>
        <th>Employee Works in</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Dheeraj Kumar</td>
        <td>Pune</td>
        <td>Tieto</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Revan</td>
        <td>Wagholi</td>
        <td>Microsoft</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Deepali</td>
        <td>karvenagar</td>
        <td>Google</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Amol</td>
        <td>Bavdan</td>
        <td>Chevron</td>

</tr>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="location = 'AddOrganisation.jsp'">ADD Organization</button>

<button type="button" onclick="location = 'AddEmployee.jsp'">ADD Employee</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see the question, only a requirement. What have you tried, there is a static table here, where are you going to store the values (DB, file, cache, cookie, session, ...). Then where is the JSP or JSTL to generate the table with those values. You only have a HTML template, but nothing functional, this is a bit short to ask for help, you should search for tutorial (I suggest you a good JSP/JSTL tutorial)

Answer (score -2):

You can use a typical `Spring MVC` like

Spring Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/organizations", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("organizationForm") @Validated User user,
            BindingResult result, Model model,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)

Spring Form in jsp :    
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="organizationForm" action="/organizations">
<form:input path="name" type="text" />
```

Use Model attribute to map your input dynamically formed from jsp to Controller and store the result into same object so that it can be viewed in Home Page.

you will need SPring libraries like

> org.springframework.asm-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.beans-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.context-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.core-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.expression-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.web-x.y.z.jar
>
> spring-web.jar

Refer any `Spring MVC` with Model attribute implementation that will serve your purpose.